# Sobre as tags [mongo] e [mongodb]

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags-sinônimas

As tags [mongo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo) e [mongodb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), na minha opinião e pelo o que diz as wikis das tags, deveriam ser sinônimas.

Mas qual deve ser a principal? Meu voto vai para [mongodb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb). No entanto, não tenho pontos suficientes para sugerir o sinônimo.

Comment: Concordo em tudo, tanto que ambas são sinônimos e que [tag:mongodb] deve ser a principal, não só por seguir o exemplo do SOen, mas porque é exatamente assim que o site https://www.mongodb.com se refere ao nome do produto. **PS:** vou aguardar até amanhã a noite, para acaso alguém queira opinar, se tudo parecer favorável (não vejo porque não seria) eu mesmo irei editar e quem quiser se juntar seja bem vindo, só peço que façam isto após as 02:00 da manhã.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Está feito! [mongodb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb)............